# Generating dump file with symbols for a .NET process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, dump

I am trying to analyze the threads and memory usage of a .NET process (w3wp.exe). For that, I am generating the .dump from the task manager, right click on the process and creating the .dmp file. I am doing this on a 64 bit machine and on the 64 bit process.

When I try to debug the threads and memory utilization on the process using the .dmp file from Visual Studio 2013, I do not see all the threads and memory data.

How I verify that the symbols are loaded correctly by default and be available to see all the threads and memory objects? Do I need to manually load the symbols for the specific dlls?

Comment: Can you use windbg and if so what are the commands you used? Did you setup the [.sympath](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-20-WinDbg-Basic-Commands) correctly?

Comment: I have not used windbg, I was trying to do this from VS.

Comment: You did setup symbol loading? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x54fht41(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please be a bit careful with the terms. You don't need symbols to see threads. Symbols are needed to resolve the call stack and variables. Seeing the call stack is probably what you need.

In VS2013:

1. Go to Debug/Options and Settings...
2. Go to Debugging/Symbols
3. [x] Microsoft Symbol Servers

For your own symbols, click the "New" button in the same dialog and add a local directory.

It is not possible to create a dump including symbols. You always get the symbols independently from the dump, e.g. via HTTP (like the Microsoft Symbols) or a local directory (created at compile time).

Visual Studio will either load the symbols, if they match the dump, or not load symbols at all, so there's no need to check whether they are loaded correctly. If you see a call stack, it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the details, this helps!

Comment: If this answer resolved the case, please click the green checkmark below the up-/down- buttons so that others know it has been solved. Thanks.